# Injection molding simulation and integration with machine learning for predicting maintenance

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Is it possible to simulate injection molding and integrating it with Machine learning using Anylogic software? Please help if there is such tools available.

Comment: Hi, any "is it possible" question is always answered with "Yes" when it comes to AnyLogic (the clue is in the name). However, SOF is not the place to ask open-ended "is it possible" questions, this is a place for specific, focussed technical issues, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . For these open questions, best use the LinkedIn forum as per https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Benjamin mentioned it is possible.

See this blog post for an implementation of DQN for reinforcement learning with a discrete action space. You could also create a similar implementation for continuous action spaces using PPO or a similar algorithm, or if your use case is not for RL you could again use Pypeline similarly to connect AnyLogic to your particular ML model.
https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/a-stable-connection-for-python-based-reinforcement-learning-training-on-anylogic-models

Hope this helps. Thanks